# Convert nvarchar value to Decimal or Numeric datatype?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column called 'Market value' in my SQL table where values of this column is like '+000000034567.4563' (18 char length including + symbol) and datatype is `NVARCHAR`.

I need to apply group by and take sum of 'Market Value' but group by does not work with `NVARCHAR` data type. So I am converting using `CONVERT`.

```
SELECT CONVERT(Numeric(18,4), '+000000034567.4563')
```

But I am getting output is '34567.4563' But my expectation is '+000000034567.4563'.

How can I achieve this using SQL?

Comment: What is the reason for you to expect `+000000034567.4563`? Why are you storing numbers as varchar in the first place?

Comment: Well, you won't get the `+` sign before your number as it already denotes a positive number but if it's a negative number you would get it in your conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use Format to convert it to your desired string representation again
like this

```
SELECT format(CONVERT(numeric(18,4), '+000000034567.4563'), '+000000000000.0000')
```

and use it to calculate and then format

```
SELECT format(sum(CONVERT(numeric(18,4), yt.[Market Value])), '+000000000000.0000')
from yourtable yt
group by yt.whatever
```

Comment: Thanks Manfred,

It has worked as I was expecting.

I hope Format does not effect the performance once data volume increases.

Thanks Again.....

Answer (score 0):

Check this code if it will help you in any way. It was written on MySQL Language.

```
Select Concat(Left(Market_Value,1),
        Repeat('0',(Length(Market_value)-Length(concat(left(Market_Value,1),
        sum(substring(Market_value,2,Length(Market_Value))))))),
        sum(substring(Market_value,2,Length(Market_Value)))) as Market_Value 
        from Test57 group by Market_value;
```